# Gâteaux derivative of classic DIrichlet energy in dimension higher than 1

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variational-calculus

I need to calculate the Gâteaux derivatives of some functional, and I started playing a bit with very simple cases. I know there's the VariationalMethods package that's required, but I don't know how to make things work in higher dimensions.

Let's say I want to calculate the derivative with respect to $u$ of

$$ J(u) = \frac{1}{2} \int |\nabla u|^2 dx.$$

If I am in dimension 1, I type `VariationalD[1/2 u'[x]^2 , u[x], x]` and it gives me `-u''[x]` as it's supposed to be, but I can't seem to make it work in higher dimensions. How should I write that?

I tried using `Norm[Grad[u[x], {x}]^2` but it doesn't work, I'm doing some mistake with the syntax.

Comment: I do not know what a Gâteaux derivative is, but in higher dimension you need the notion of  a directional derivative.

Comment: It's exactly that. A directional derivative where the direction is a function though. It's a generalization in infinite dimensional spaces

Comment: The directional derivative is defined as: "Grad[f,vars]. dir" where dir is the direction. There are different definitions where dir is a unit vector or not. E.g. a derivative along {1,1} using a unit vector: `Grad[3 x^2 y, {x, y}] . {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]`

Comment: The second two examples in the Documentation show how to do this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/VariationalD.html I think this is what you want.

Comment: Yes! Can't believe I missed that! Thanks!